# jQuery get all rows using table.rows().data().each with pagination

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I can't find a solution online for this. I have my code like this

```
$('.validation-summary-table').dataTable({ paging: true, ordering: false });
const conflictsArray = pushConflictDatas('#conflict .validation-summary-table tbody tr.odd');

function pushConflictDatas(dataTableTr) {
    let radioButtonsConflicts = new Array();
    $(dataTableTr).each(function() {
        const currentRow = $(this).closest("tr"); // CSV row
        const nextRow = currentRow.next(); // DB row

        let currentRowObj = {
            Name: currentRow.find('td:eq(0)').text().trim(),
            isChecked: currentRow.find('td:eq(1) input[type="radio"]').is(':checked')
        }

        let nextRowObj = {
            Name: nextRow.find('td:eq(0)').text().trim(),
            isChecked: nextRow.find('td:eq(1) input[type="radio"]').is(':checked')
        }

        radioButtonsConflicts.push([currentRowObj, nextRowObj]);
    });

    return radioButtonsConflicts;
}
```

This worked fine until I found out it wasn't getting all table rows on the next pages when I click a button, only the current page and nothing else. I need to get all the rows and push them to an array for my ajax request. So I found this code from their docs:

```
var table = $(conflictTable).DataTable();

table.rows('.odd').data().each(function (value, index) {
    console.log('index: ', index)
    console.log('value: ', value)
} );
```

However this only selects `<tr>` on the current page, just like what the old function does. If I move to the next page, it will "append" it. If I remove the selector `.odd`, it would get all the rows from all paginated pages, but I'm writing a code that targets the next row and I want to only select rows with a specific class name before I do such. How do I do this?

Comment: If you select your rows through jQuery/DOM selectors (class like `.odd`, tag like `<tr>` etc) you can only find/select elements that are currently on the DOM. Next pages ARE NOT on the DOM, so you can't select them (and their data) this way. You need to use **DataTables API** to select the data you need; and the criteria you will use have to be **not-DOM-based**.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the following code to get all table data:

```
let table_data = table.rows({ search: 'applied'}).data();
```